# C++ templates inside templates

Tags: c++, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where and why do I have to put “template” and “typename” on dependent names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-template-and-typename-on-dependent-names)

Here's my problem:

```
template<typename TypeName> class Bubu
{
   ...
   vector<TypeName>::iterator Foo()
   {
      ...
   }
   ...
}
```

This gives:

error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'Foo'

If I change the typename to an actual type, like int or SomeClass, it works:

```
vector<int>::iterator Foo(){}
```

What I want to have is something like:

```
Bubu<SomeClassType> bubuInstance;
vector<SomeClassType>::iterator it = bubuInstance.Foo();
```

What's wrong? How do I fix it?

---

Comment: What? That's not a duplicate at all. Just because it's talking about the same thing doesn't inherently make it a duplicate. The OP didn't even know what `typename` _is_, let alone know to ask how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Search for "dependent names" on google.

Anyway to fix it use typename :

```
template<typename TypeName> class Bubu
{
   ...
   typename vector<TypeName>::iterator Foo()
   {
      ...
   }
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to prefix 'typename', and also finish-off your class with a semi-colon ';'

```
template<typename TypeName>
class Bubu
{
    typename vector<typename TypeName>::iterator Foo()
    {
    }
};
```